# Выделение шаблонной строки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Создал пользовательскую строку данных в своей таблице. Вот XAML - разметка:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="244" Margin="468,535,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="521"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false" ItemsSource="{ Binding TestDataTable}" >

        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMerged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                    <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
                                    <Border  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Grid.Column="1">
                                                <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                                        <Run Text="{Binding _1}"/>
                                                    </TextBlock.Inlines>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </Border>
                                            <DataGridRowHeader SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="1" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = _1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="2" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = _2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="3" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = _3, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="4" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = _4, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="5" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path = _5, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Вот код C#:

```
TestDataTable = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
        {
            TestDataTable.Add(new TestModel((i % 2  == 0 ? true : false), i.ToString(), (i + 1).ToString(), (i + 2).ToString(), (i + 3).ToString(), (i + 4).ToString()));
        }

public class TestModel
{
    public bool IsMerged { get; set; }
    public string _1 { get; set; }
    public string _2 { get; set; }
    public string _3 { get; set; }
    public string _4 { get; set; }

    public string _5 { get; set; }

    public TestModel(bool ism, string _1, string _2, string _3, string _4, string _5)
    {
        IsMerged = ism;
        this._1 = _1;
        this._2 = _2;
        this._3 = _3;
        this._4 = _4;
        this._5 = _5;
    }
}
```

И привязываю к DataContext. Всё работает как предполагал, вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, вот эта новая строка(0, 2 etc) не выделяется мышью. Я пробовал привязать триггер к ControlTemplate(закомментированный блок в XAML-коде), но это не работает. Подскажите, как верно сделать выделение строки. Спасибо.

Comment: Надо посмотреть как штатный шаблон устроен и воспроизвести недостающие части в своем...

Comment: @АндрейNOP может посоветуете пример? А то я как-то не нашел

Comment: Как обычно бывает с DataGrid, всё здесь не так просто, как я предполагал. Пока не придумал решения. Если что-то получится — напишу ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP благодарю, сам пытался, тоже пока не получилось.

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил ответ, может быть будет интересно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При такой разметке строка подчиняется выделению, однако, поменять цвет выделенной ячейки не получается, как бы я не бился. Если кто - то знает - подскажите, буду рад.

```
            <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_MouseLeftButtonDown" ></EventSetter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMerged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" x:Name="SelectedMergedRow">
                                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                                <DataGridCellsPresenter.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
                                                        <DataGridCell Height="20">
                                                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding NameNull}"/>
                                                            <DataGridCell.Style>
                                                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF"/>
                                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                                                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}}"/>
                                                                        </Trigger>
                                                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                                                        </Trigger>
                                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                                </Style>
                                                            </DataGridCell.Style>
                                                        </DataGridCell>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </DataGridCellsPresenter.Template>
                                            </DataGridCellsPresenter>
                                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```